# How can I format a list into a tuple with sub-tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I'm just having a bit of trouble getting my head around lists and tuples in python. 
What I have is a list(? I think) and it needs to be converted to a tuple in the specific format given below? 
How would I go about this?
I have:

```
['A, B, C, D, e, f, g, h, i', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9',]
```

How can this be formatted to a tuple with a sub-tuple such as

```
[
    ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')),
    ('1', '2', '3', '4', ('5', '6', '7', '8', '9')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: You forgot to specify by what rules each string in your list is converted to a tuple with a nested tuple. Also, those values in the tuples are probably meant to be still strings, but your output sample is lacking quotes.

Comment: I fixed the later point raised by Martijn. It is now up to you to review that change and to further edit your question to [explain more clearly your needs](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but the 5-9 elements in each 'list item' need to be in the nested tuple

Comment: @user3728778: it is not a list item; it is as string. You can *turn that into a list* by splitting the string, say, on those commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each item in your list on the comma; here I am assuming you also always have a space after the comma:

```
result = []
for elem in inputlist:
    elems = elem.split(', ')
    elems[4:] = [tuple(elems[4:])]
    result.append(tuple(elems))
```

The dance with `tuple()` and slice assignment is required to make it possible to build the outer tuple. The `elems[4:]` assignment here replaces the 5th-until-end part of the list with a list with just the one tuple.

If your strings contain commas without the whitespace or the whitespace is variable, you could use a split-and-strip strategy:

```
elems = [e.strip() for e in elem.split(',')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = ['A, B, C, D, e, f, g, h, i', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9',]
>>> result = []
>>> for elem in inputlist:
...     elems = elem.split(', ')
...     elems[4:] = [tuple(elems[4:])]
...     result.append(tuple(elems))
... 
>>> result
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')), ('1', '2', '3', '4', ('5', '6', '7', '8', '9'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the 5-9 elements in each 'list item' need to be in the nested tuple

Fixed size ? So what about:

```
import re

lst = ['A, B, C, D, e, f, g, h, i', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9',]

def prefix_by_four(lst):
    return tuple(lst[:4]) + (tuple(lst[4:]),)
#          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^              ^^
#   make a tuple with the   note how tuples are nested here:
#   first 4 items               make a tuple of one element `( ... ,)`
#                               containing a tuple with the remaining items

result = [ prefix_by_four(re.split(r',\s*',item)) for item in lst ]
#                                   ^^^^^^
#                          split on `,` followed by
#                          zero or more spaces

from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Producing:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')),
 ('1', '2', '3', '4', ('5', '6', '7', '8', '9'))]
```

Here I used an "helper function" to do the grouping. A [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) would have been possible, but less readable, I think.